# Netty Data Validation Issues

Tags: netty

I've modified the echo example Netty provides to a ping-pong benchmarking test that computes the average latency with respect to different message sizes that are sent out and received by the client. The problem that I'm having is with data validation.

The problems are the following,

1. The default capacity for the receive buffer for the client channel is by default 2048. This is a problem because I want to test over larger message sizes (4 MB).
2. Over large numbers of iterations, the capacity for the receive buffer becomes smaller. This leads to validation errors when messages become larger than 64 bytes.

Any advice or help in resolving these problems would be great. Thanks.

Here's my code, EchoClient:

```
public final class EchoClient {

static final boolean SSL = System.getProperty("ssl") != null;
static final String HOST = System.getProperty("host", "127.0.0.1");
static final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", "8007"));
static final int SIZE = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("size", "256"));

static final String TRANSPORT = System.getProperty("transport", "Nio"); 
static final int ITER = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("iter", "1000"));
static final int WARMUP_ITERS = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("warmupIters", Integer.toString(ITER/10)));

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Configure SSL.git
    final SslContext sslCtx;
    if (SSL) {
        sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
            .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE).build();
    } else {
        sslCtx = null;
    }

    // Configure the transport channel
    Class transportChannel = (TRANSPORT.equals("Nio")) ? NioSocketChannel.class : OioSocketChannel.class;  

    // Configure the client.
    EventLoopGroup group = (TRANSPORT.equals("Nio")) ? new NioEventLoopGroup() : new OioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(group)
         .channel(transportChannel)
         .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
         .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
             @Override
             public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                 ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                 if (sslCtx != null) {
                     p.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc(), HOST, PORT));
                 }
                 //p.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
                 p.addLast(new EchoClientHandler());
             }
         });

        // Start the client.
        ChannelFuture f = b.connect(HOST, PORT).sync();

        // Wait until the connection is closed.
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
        // Shut down the event loop to terminate all threads.
        group.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
}
```

EchoServer:

```
public final class EchoServer {

static final boolean SSL = System.getProperty("ssl") != null;
static final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", "8007"));
static final String TRANSPORT = System.getProperty("transport", "Nio"); 

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Configure SSL.
    final SslContext sslCtx;
    if (SSL) {
        SelfSignedCertificate ssc = new SelfSignedCertificate();
        sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(ssc.certificate(), ssc.privateKey()).build();
    } else {
        sslCtx = null;
    }

    // Configure the transport channel
    Class transportChannel = (TRANSPORT.equals("Nio")) ? NioServerSocketChannel.class : OioServerSocketChannel.class;  

    // Configure the server
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = (TRANSPORT.equals("Nio")) ? new NioEventLoopGroup(1) : new OioEventLoopGroup(1);
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = (TRANSPORT.equals("Nio")) ? new NioEventLoopGroup() : new OioEventLoopGroup(); 

    final EchoServerHandler serverHandler = new EchoServerHandler();
    try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
         .channel(transportChannel)
         .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 100)
         .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
         .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
             @Override
             public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                 ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                 if (sslCtx != null) {
                     p.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc()));
                 }
                 //p.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
                 p.addLast(serverHandler);
             }
         });

        // Start the server.
        ChannelFuture f = b.bind(PORT).sync();

        // Wait until the server socket is closed.
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
        // Shut down all event loops to terminate all threads.
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
}
```

EchoClientHandler:

```
public class EchoClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

long startTime; 
long endTime;
long durations = 0;

private ChannelHandlerContext ctx;

int iter = EchoClient.ITER;
int skip = EchoClient.WARMUP_ITERS;
int j = iter;
int size = 1;

/**
 * Creates a client-side handler.
 */
public EchoClientHandler() {
}

private ByteBuf createMsg(int size) {
    ByteBuf message = Unpooled.directBuffer(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < message.capacity(); i ++) {
        message.writeByte((byte) i);
    }

    return message;
}

private void checkDataValidity(ByteBuf msgRecvByClient) {
    ByteBuf msgSentByClient = createMsg(size);

    if (!msgRecvByClient.equals(msgSentByClient)) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: Message was corrupted");
        ctx.close();
    }
}

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    ByteBuf msg = createMsg(size);
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    ctx.writeAndFlush(msg);
    j--;
}

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    checkDataValidity((ByteBuf)msg);

    if (j < iter - skip) {
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        durations += (endTime - startTime)/(double)1000;

        if (j == 0) {
            System.out.printf("%d bytes has latency avg: %10.2f us\n", size, durations/((double)(iter-skip)));
            durations = 0;
            j = iter;
            size *= 2;
            if (size > EchoClient.SIZE) ctx.close();
        }
    }

    ByteBuf newMsg = createMsg(size);

    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    ctx.write(newMsg);
    j--;   
}

@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    //ByteBuf newMsg = createMsg(size);

    //startTime = System.nanoTime();
    //ctx.writeAndFlush(newMsg);
    //j--;

    ctx.flush();
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
    // Close the connection when an exception is raised.
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ctx.close();
}
}
```

EchoServerHandler:

```
public class EchoServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    ctx.write(msg);
}

@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    ctx.flush();
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
    // Close the connection when an exception is raised.
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ctx.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not have any message boundaries hence netty will read the data from the socket according to internal buffer sizes and how much data is available on the socket at any point. If you want to read messages of certain length then you should define that application level message boundaries. A very simple example of how to have such message boundaries can be found here:

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/factorial/FactorialServerInitializer.java#L49

Typically, people will use a more standard message encoding format like google protocol buffers.